# Get the error codes in Twython exceptions in python

Tags: python-2.7, error-handling, twython

I want to capture the error codes due to which exception occurs in twython. How can that be done? Right now, I am only able to capture the TwythonAuthError for protected accounts but not for errors like 403 or 404 etc. I want to save these error codes in some file along with the username for whom this error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try/except to capture the error and then access it with .error_code like this:

```
try:
    twython.create_friendship(user_id=userID)
except TwythonError as e:
    print e.error_code
```

Comment: Does that work?  When I have except TwythonError as e and an exception occurs,  Python throws a NameError and says TwythonError is not defined.

Comment: Never mind, realized you have to include from twython import TwythonError